# Use karmarkar with integer constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, scilab

I'd like to use Scilab's Karmarkar (https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.2/fr_FR/karmarkar.html) considering only integer on solutions, like the parameter "I" on vartype's Octave (https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Linear-Programming.html). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. That is an algorithm for linear programs, not integer programs (although integer programs can be solved as series of linear programs).

[SciGLPK](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/SciGLPK) might be a good option, if you can get it to install. I'd recommend using PuLP though if possible, its a better interface.